# Select columns then update using values selected

Tags: mysql

Right so I am migrating data from an old db structure to a new one and it is all going swell except for one table.

I have everything in the new structure but I now need to change some of the IDs around.

To put it simply I have noticed I now have a table the due to the old data has a few duplicates. The only difference is the PK.

Elsewhere in the db I have tables referencing this table and they need to reference the same rows.

I have run a query that give me all the PKs I want to keep and all the PKs that I want to change in the foreign key columns of the other tables.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT p1.priceID, p2.priceID 
FROM price p1 LEFT JOIN price p2 
ON (p1.productTimeID = p2.productTimeID 
AND p1.priceTypeID = p2.priceTypeID 
AND p1.fareTypeID = p2.fareTypeID 
AND p1.priceID < p2.priceID)
WHERE p1.priceID != p2.priceID
```

p1 is the PK that I want to keep and p2 is the FK I will search for in the other tables and replace with its corresponding p1 PK

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an INNER JOIN between that query and any other table that you want to UPDATE the priceID, and put there the new value:

```
UPDATE someOtherTable s
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT p1.priceID AS newPriceID, p2.priceID AS oldPriceID
 FROM price p1 
 LEFT JOIN price p2 
   ON (p1.productTimeID = p2.productTimeID 
     AND p1.priceTypeID = p2.priceTypeID 
     AND p1.fareTypeID = p2.fareTypeID 
     AND p1.priceID < p2.priceID)
 WHERE p1.priceID != p2.priceID 
) a
ON s.priceID = a.oldPriceID
SET s.priceID = a.newPriceID
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple!